# How-to log the authentication traffic generated by GraphServiceClient?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using NuGet packages Microsoft.Graph 5.29.0 and Azure.Identity 1.10.2 in .NET Framework 4.8.

I implemented a `DelegatingHandler` as documented in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/dev/docs/logging-requests.md and it works great, but it does not include the authentication traffic.

I use the class `TokenCredential` mostly as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=csharp, and
noticed that `TokenCredentialOptions` has property `Diagnostics` with [many interesting properties related to logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.tokencredentialoptions.diagnostics?view=azure-dotnet#azure-identity-tokencredentialoptions-diagnostics), but I couldn't determine how to use it.

Do I have a simple way to capture/log the authentication traffic?
If possible, I'm looking for a simple solution that does not involve a 3rd party library.

My goal is to log when the authentication happens (and if possible measure its time taken), not to capture the request payload or the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by configuring (**GraphServiceClient**) logging in your application

Here's a general approach using .NET / C#:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Graph;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create an instance of GraphServiceClient
        var graphServiceClient = GetGraphServiceClient();

        // Set up logging
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole(); // You can customize this to log to a file.
        });

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("GraphServiceClient");

        // Set the logger for the GraphServiceClient
        graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;

        // Now, any requests made through GraphServiceClient will be logged
        // with the configured logger.

        // Make a request
        var user = graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine($"User Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
    }

    static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
    {
        // Set up your authentication here, depending on your application's authentication flow.
        // For example, using Client Credentials flow:

        var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("YourAppId")
            .WithClientSecret("YourClientSecret")
            .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantId"))
            .Build();

        var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        // Create an instance of GraphServiceClient using the auth provider
        var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        return graphServiceClient;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that log only what is necessary for debugging purposes and to secure the logs appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
Finally I opted for the [Azure SDK diagnostics](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md).
One reason why I did not go with your solution is that it is a .NET Framework 4.8 app that will be installed on many servers, and I want to avoid as much as possible additional references (due to the assembly bindings issues)